# Python logging, how to have a single logger for multiple scripts of the same project (Python 2.7)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-logging

For any script that needs a history of it's run kept, I use the following code to create a logging process via the `logging` module and copy paste it in:

```py
    from datetime import datetime
    import logging
    from logging import handlers
   
    dt_now = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
    sender = 'sender@domainname.com'
    recipients ='recipient@domainname.com'
    sub_err = "Process Failed"

    # Set up logging 
    log_file = ("//some_server/some_dir/another_dir/"
                "logs/{}.txt".format(dt_now))
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handle = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    stream_handle = logging.StreamHandler()
    email_handle = handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost="mailhost.domain.com",
                                                fromaddr=sender,
                                                toaddrs=recipients,
                                                subject=sub_err,
                                                secure=None)
    email_handle.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    file_handle.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    stream_handle.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handles = [email_handle, file_handle, stream_handle]
    for handle in handles:
        handle.setFormatter(log_format)
        logger.addHandler(handle)
```

This works well for me, it logs everything to a file, sends me an email if an exception is hit, and will print to console if I'm working with one to debug. Now for any project it's pretty typical for me to have 2 or more scripts and what I usually do is just copy and paste this in to each script and I get a single log file for the process. In addition I usually have a project module with some commonly used functions that both scripts will use. What I'm wondering is how I would go about housing my logging process in this common file so each script just imports it in and uses all the same handles and log file.

Comment: You can write a function that you can import and call in each script, or you write a logger configuration that can be parsed by `logging.config.fileConfig`.

Comment: Oh yup that worked, for some reason I thought you couldn't do that with the logging module. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As [@chepner commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69031054/python-logging-how-to-have-a-single-logger-for-multiple-scripts-of-the-same-pro#comment122002424_69031054), you can create a function that enables the logger. You can also create a logging configuration file that you can parse via `logging.config.fileConfig`.

#### Function

You can create a function that creates the logger with the correct handler. Note that this function needs to be called only once for the entire run of the application. Indeed, the `logging` config is defined globally across the entire app.

```py
def init_logging():
    from datetime import datetime
    import logging
    from logging import handlers

    dt_now = datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
    sender = 'sender@domainname.com'
    recipients ='recipient@domainname.com'
    sub_err = "Process Failed"

    # Set up logging 
    log_file = ("//some_server/some_dir/another_dir/logs/{}.txt".format(dt_now))
    logger = logging.getLogger("foobar")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handle = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    stream_handle = logging.StreamHandler()
    email_handle = handlers.SMTPHandler(
        mailhost="mailhost.domain.com",
        fromaddr=sender,
        toaddrs=recipients,
        subject=sub_err,
        secure=None
    )
    email_handle.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    file_handle.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    stream_handle.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handles = [email_handle, file_handle, stream_handle]
    for handle in handles:
        handle.setFormatter(log_format)
        logger.addHandler(handle)
```

You can then use the logger created here inside any script like this:

```py
from .logging import init_logging

init_logging()

# foobar is accessible, and has all the handlers as defined in init_logging
foobarlogger = getLogger("foobar")
foobarlogger.info("Hello, world!")
```

**Note:** Since the definition of the handler is global, you can also put the code, not inside a function but inside the `__init__.py` file of a module, defining it at first import, and making it usable throughout the entire app.

---

#### `fileConfig`

Another way to proceed would be to use [`logging.config.fileConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html). You can setup your logging handlers, loggers, formatters etc. inside this file.

Create a `logging.conf` file:

```ini
[loggers]
keys=root, foobar

[handlers]
keys=console, file, email

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console

[logger_foobar]
level=DEBUG
handlers=file, console, email
qualname=foobar
propagate=0

[handler_file]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=({"/some_server/some_dir/another_dir/logs/log.txt"})

[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter

[handler_email]
class=handlers.SMTPHandler
level=WARNING
args=('mailhost.domain.com', 'sender@domainname.com', ['recipient@domainname.com'], 'Process Failed')
formatter=simpleFormatter

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

Then, you can load this file and create all the logging environment with:

```py
import logging.config

# only do it once, since the loaded logging config is global!
logging.config.fileConfig("logging.conf")

# then, in any file, you can do:
foobarlogger = logging.getLogger("foobar")
foobarlogger.info("Hello, world!")
```